# Fit images with different size into a div of same class and number of div equals to total number images

Tags: html, css

I have a main container div, called "container" which contains sub div, called "img-container" inside which image tag is used.

Lets suppose I have total number of 4 images of different size. Now I want these images to be fit inside "img-container".

What it is now :

[image]

What it should be :

[image]

and in the same time, it should be responsive.

Thank you

Comment: please provide your code as well - what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div id="img-container" >
    <img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" src="yourimg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put width and height 100% to the `img` and set your fixed width and height to your `div`.
HTML:

```
<div class="fill">    
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-zzcv3yDERgc/VSbJnz5KdQI/AAAAAAAAHQk/BL7sjHGK5sc/s1600/test.jpg">    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.fill {
    width:100px; height:100px;
}
div.fill img {    
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rx37G/48/